# Entering a null value from the keyboard or using menus

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

How do I insert a NULL value into a cell using the keyboard or a menu option?

For example, in some programs, typing `CONTROL + 0`  results in a null value being inserted and the text "NULL" being displayed, but this is not the same as typing NULL in the cell, since this would be treated as text.

Comment: I'm not sure Excel even has the concept of a `null` value. Doesn't just deleting the cell's contents work?

Comment: CSV fields have the concept of NULL if field delimiters are used and Excel handles CSV files, though poorly. However, the only way that I know to get a null value into the file is using Notepad.